# How to make real parallel programming in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to do parallel processing to speed up the task in Python.

I used `apply_async` but the cpu only consumes 30%. How to fully utilize the cpu?

Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

def calc_score(df, i, j, score):
    score[i,j] = df.loc[i, 'data'] + df.loc[j, 'data']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    score = np.zeros([100, 100])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(100):
            pool.apply_async(calc_score, (df, i, j, score))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Be aware of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)

Comment: How to avoid it?

Comment: You can't avoid the GIL in Python. Consider switching to a genuinely multi-thread capable programming language, e.g. [Go](https://golang.org/).

Comment: Then what are your recommendations?

Comment: Spend several months learning another programming language, more suited to your needs. Python (or any single other language) is not a [panacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panacea). BTW, parallel program design is always difficult

Comment: Any packages that can do real parallel processing?

Comment: The GIL is essential in Python implementation, and it would be difficult to implement Python in a genuinely multi-threaded way. So I recommend learning and using some other programming language. Look into several ones, including Common Lisp (using  [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)...) & [Rust](http://rust-lang.org/) & Go.  However, there is [*No Siliver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) and parallel processing is really hard.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There is no problem with GIL when using `multiprocessing`.  This is just hate speech against Python, I am afraid there is no real value in your comments.

Comment: Yes, but as [Jay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404065/841108) shows multi-processing is not really working as well as people hope from Python. My point is that real parallel processing is very hard, and Python is not (always) the right tool for it. Most HPC software are parallel and not fully coded in Python

Comment: @zvone: feel free to give a better answer to that question. I still believe that Python is sometimes overused for parallel processing. Indeed, it is just my opinion

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I will not discuss your opinions on what people hope from Python.

Comment: @John I fail to see what you are trying to do here. The idea of "utilizing the cpu" should be to do as much work in as little time as possible - not to spend 100% of CPU. In your case, the correct way to do things faster would be to let numpy do the calculation which you are doing in Python: `score[i,j] = df.loc[i, 'data'] + df.loc[j, 'data']`. That is what numpy is meant for.

Comment: @zvone

Thank you for your comments.
I want  the CPU to be utilized by over 80%. Moreover, my example is just for illustration for parallel processing. What I want is a parallel processing solution for general problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't utilize 100% CPU with `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())` . It starts your worker function on the number of core given by you but also looks for a free core. If you want to utilize maximum CPU with **multiprocessing** you should use **multiprocessing** **Process** class. It keeps spinning new thread. But be aware it will breakdown system if your CPU doesn't have memory to spin new thread.

Comment: I used multiprocessing Process class but the CPU utilization is still 30%.

Comment: Any other methods?

Comment: Hi, can you share your code what exactly you are trying to do? You can't go for 100% CPU utilization if your task contains a lot of IO bound, in this case, OS will make CPU idle.

Answer (score 0):

"CPU utilization" should be about performance, i.e. you want to do the job in as little time as possible. There is no generic way to do that. If there was a generic way to optimize software, then there would be no slow software, right?

You seem to be looking for a different thing: spend as much CPU time as possible, so that it does not *sit idly*. That may seem like the same thing, but is absolutely not.

Anyway, if you want to spend 100% of CPU time, this script will do that for you:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def loop_until_t(t):
    while time.time() < t:
        pass

def waste_cpu_for_n_seconds(num_seconds, num_processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
    t0 = time.time()
    t = t0 + num_seconds
    print("Begin spending CPU time (in {} processes)...".format(num_processes))
    with multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes) as pool:
        pool.map(loop_until_t, num_processes*[t])
    print("Done.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    waste_cpu_for_n_seconds(15)
```

If, instead, you want your program to run faster, you will not do that with an *"illustration for parallel processing"*, as you call it - you need an actual problem to be solved.